# what sort of set up would i need to create an electro magnetic chair with no legs

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a furniture design student therefore please keep it simple. a system strong enough to hold the avergae male of say 90 kg is this possible even....

Comment: This is still a challenging problem today, because something would be needed to keep the seat of the chair from drifting laterally. A fixture could be used to hold it in, but any such fixture would be more expensive/impractical than simply having legs on the chair.

Comment: An obligatory ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Vladimir_Harkonnen

Answer (score 2):

Some has done this with a bed http://www.dvice.com/archives/2012/05/maglev-bed-lets.php. With the use of the naturally strong rare earth magnets (neodymium magnets). For a chair it would be hard to levitate the chair any reasonable distance, as you would need a decently powerful magnet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're thinking of using disk magnets like [these ones](http://www.first4magnets.com/circular-disc--rod-magnets-8-c.asp). The force between this type of magnet is [somewhat complicated to calculate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Force_between_two_cylindrical_magnets), but at distances larger than the depth of the disk the force falls away as distance squared i.e.:

$$ F \propto \frac{1}{d^2} $$

This means the force falls very rapidly with distance. In the bed that Dan mentioned I'd guess the distance is a few cm, while for a chair the seat would be about 40cm above the floor. That means the force between the chair and the floor would about a hundred times less than the force between the floor and the bed. You'd need either a hundred times as many magnets or magnets a hundred times as strong (the latter isn't physically possible!).

You could certainly have your seat suspended a few cm above some base, like the bed, but I'm guessing you'd like the chair to be apparently floating in mid air. If so I don't think you'll be able to find magnets strong enough.